# Unable to deserialize a json object

Tags: c#, .net, json

I'm using JavaScriptSerializer and when I try to deserialize a JSON object as

```
Json.Deserialize<List<HeyWatchVideo>>(Request("video"));
```

I get following Exception:

> MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for type of 'System.String'.

I tried matching my .NET classes, and the types of their properties just as close to my json object, but still getting above exception

My JSON object:

```
[{
    "url": "http://media.heywatch.com.s3.amazonaws.com/14/14/a0f356a48381092e6e2a34021ce86b19/11002247",
    "specs": {
        "size": 3808,
        "video": {
            "fps": 11.63,
            "height": 360,
            "length": 61,
            "width": 640,
            "aspect": 1.78,
            "codec": "mpeg4",
            "container": "mov",
            "rotation": 0,
            "bitrate": 507,
            "pix_format": "yuv420p",
            "stream": 0.1
        },
        "thumb": "http://media.heywatch.com.s3.amazonaws.com/14/14/ad59fa501d1b9e826552dfc010cf1c98/11002247.jpg",
        "audio": {
            "sample_rate": 11025,
            "channels": 1,
            "codec": "aac",
            "bitrate": 38,
            "synched": true,
            "stream": 0
        },
        "mime_type": "video/mp4"
    },
    "title": "elves.mp4",
    "filename": "11002247",
    "link": "http://heywatch.com/video/21091957.bin",
    "updated_at": "2013-01-14T15:44:53+01:00",
    "created_at": "2013-01-14T15:44:53+01:00",
    "id": 21091957
}]
```

My Classes

```
public class HeyWatchVideo
{
    public DateTime Created_At { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Specs { get; set; }
    public DateTime Updated_At { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}

public class HeyWatchVideoSpecs
{
    public HeyWatchVideoSpecsAudio Audio { get; set; }
    public HeyWatchVideoSpecsVideo Video { get; set; }
    public string Thumb { get; set; }
    public string Mime_type { get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }
}

public class HeyWatchVideoSpecsVideo
{
    public int Rotation { get; set; }
    public double Aspect { get; set; }
    public string Container { get; set; }
    public string Codec { get; set; }
    public int Length { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Bitrate { get; set; }
    public string Pix_format { get; set; }
    public double Fps { get; set; }
    public double Stream { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
}

public class HeyWatchVideoSpecsAudio
{
    public int Channels { get; set; }
    public int Sample_rate { get; set; }
    public string Codec { get; set; }
    public bool Synched { get; set; }
    public int Bitrate { get; set; }
    public int Stream { get; set; }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What does "unable" mean? What error do you get?

Comment: You forgot to provide information about the JSON serializer you are using as well as the code where you are actually performing this serialization. Also you forgot to mention what exactly the problem is. All you said was `Unable` but could you be a little more precise? Are you getting an exception? Is the target object being created but some properties not deserialized? If so which?

Comment: At a minimum, you need to indicate a) What you're trying to do b) What you've tried so far c) What didn't work about your attempts

Comment: Why is this tagged as JavaScript? It does not seem to have anything to do with it...

Comment: Looks like you did a decent job editing your question. The code examples are sufficient to recreate the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was solved. My .Net Classes didn't match exactly as Json object. (Both are in the question)

When they were matched, this error went away